# Tri State Chech box for ToolStripDropDownButton

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, toolstripmenu

I have statusbar strip with ToolStripMenuItems. I need to gruop the Toolstrip menu items and Implement TriStateCheckbox functionality,

1. Is it Possible to Create checkbox with ToolStripMenitems?
2. If its not Possible for Point 1, then How to Add TreeView to StatusStrip.
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a three-state menu item, you can set `CheckState` of each `ToolStripMenuItem` to `Indeterminate`, `Checked` or `Unchecked`.

[image]

Also if you want to use a tree-view control (which doesn't have builtin support for three-state check boxes) or something like [this control](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/59514/Simple-Tri-State-TreeView), you should know, you can host any control in drop-down using `ToolStripControlHost`. For example, here is a `ToolStripTreeView` control:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;
[ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability(ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.ContextMenuStrip)]
public class ToolStripTreeView : ToolStripControlHost
{
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility( DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public TreeView TreeViewControl { get { return (TreeView)Control; } }
    public ToolStripTreeView() : base(CreateControl()) { }
    private static TreeView CreateControl()
    {
        var t = new TreeView();
        return t;
    }
}
```

[image]